# series converges by comparison test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am currently studying series and using the comparison test to determine whether or not a series converges.

Is this an acceptable proof using the comparison test? (I have generalised a and b)

If we know that $a<b$ ($a$ and $b$ are functions of $i$)

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{a}{b} < \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{b}{b} = 1 $$

Now since a series larger than a/b converges, using the comparison test we can say that the sequence a/b converges?

Thanks in regards.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{b}{b}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty1$ means to sum up infinitely many $1$ and is equal to $\infty$.

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac bb=\sum_{i=1}^\infty1$ obviously does not converge, so the comparison test cannot be used in this way.

Comment: Why does $sum_{i=1}^\infty1$ not converge?

Comment: @user11015000 Because the terms don't converge to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is your use of the comparison test incorrect as pointed out in the comments and answers, there is actually no way to determine if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ exists.

Take $a_i = 1$ and $b_i=i^\alpha$. The series will converge if and only if $\alpha>1$.

Comment: Thanks, but my use of the comparison test is fine.